# Recovering from a bottle of ferrous chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My bottle of ferrous chloride powder/crystals was years in shelf and it turned dark brown. If I break up the clumps I can see a little bit of yellow layers. I suspect it's a combination of iron oxide and ferric chloride.

I want to convert it back to green ferrous chloride and I'm looking for cheap ways to do that. My first idea is to dissolve it and stir it with nails, but I find it hard to dissolve in water. I'm not sure if adding HCl helps but it's too expensive for converting the whole 500g.

Better options or ideas?

Comment: As you suspect, your oxidized stuff is a mixture of $\ce{FeCl3 + Fe2O3}$, more or less hydrated. Anyway, it will not get dissolved in water, or even in dilute $\ce{HCl}$ solutions. The only possibility is using rather concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ solution. Maybe not the most concentrated solution ($36$%). Try with a mixture $1+1$ and $1 g$ oxidized mixture. And if you succeed, add some nails, or some steel wool. If the solution gets discolored, the transformation into $\ce{FeCl2}$  is over. Take care to prevent contact with air.

Comment: Nails and steel wool contain other acid-soluble metals.  I'd rather buy it fresh.